# Additional argument in operator() in boost::static_visitor

Tags: c++, performance, boost, c++14, variant

I have to create `boost::variant` object and use `static_visitor`.
Unfortunately I need extra parameter...

What solution is better? 
To have this object as field of the class and when I want to use visitor I have to create instance:

```
class Visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    Visitor(int extra): extra{extra} {}
    void operator()(const T1&) { /* ... */}
    void operator()(const T2&) { /* ... */}

private:
    int extra;
};
```

and create Visitor object each time I want to use it:

```
Visitor visitor(x);
boost::apply_visitor(visitor, t);
```

or to use boost::bind and create Visitor one time and use `boost::bind`?

```
class Visitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
    void operator()(const T1&, int extra) { /* ... */ }
    void operator()(const T2&, int extra) { /* ... */ }
};
```

*Usage:*

```
auto visitor = std::bind(SctpManager::Visitor(), std::placeholders::_1, extra);
boost::apply_visitor(visitor, t);
```

What is better (faster, more elegant) solution?

Or are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *essentially* more elegant way. You can use lambdas (if your compiler/boost version is modern enough).

The "low-tech" option is to use a struct that holds the state (3rd example):

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72dd518c10e2787a)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct T1{};
struct T2{};

struct Visitor : boost::static_visitor<>
{
    void operator()(T1 const&, int extra) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " extra:" << extra << "\n"; }
    void operator()(T2 const&, int extra) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " extra:" << extra << "\n"; }
};

int main() {
    boost::variant<T1, T2> tests[] = { T1{}, T2{} };

    {
        Visitor vis;
        for (auto v: tests)
            apply_visitor([=](auto const& v) { vis(v, 42); }, v);
    }

    {
        auto vis = [vis=Visitor{}](auto const& v) { vis(v, 1); };
        for (auto v: tests)
            apply_visitor(vis, v);
    }


    {
        struct {
            using result_type = void;
            int extra;
            void operator()(T1 const&) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " extra:" << extra << "\n"; }
            void operator()(T2 const&) const { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " extra:" << extra << "\n"; }
        } vis { 99 };

        for (auto v: tests)
            apply_visitor(vis, v);
    }
}
```

Prints

```
void Visitor::operator()(const T1&, int) const extra:42
void Visitor::operator()(const T2&, int) const extra:42
void Visitor::operator()(const T1&, int) const extra:1
void Visitor::operator()(const T2&, int) const extra:1
void main()::<unnamed struct>::operator()(const T1&) const extra:99
void main()::<unnamed struct>::operator()(const T2&) const extra:99
```